# API Gateway generating 11 sql queries per second on REG_LOG

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have sysdig running on our WSO2 API gateway machine and we notice that it fires a large number of SQL queries to the database for a minute, than waits a minute and repeats.

The query looks like this:

Every minute it goes wild, waits for a minute and goes wild again with a request of the following format:

```
SELECT REG_PATH, REG_USER_ID, REG_LOGGED_TIME, REG_ACTION, REG_ACTION_DATA
FROM REG_LOG 
WHERE REG_LOGGED_TIME>'2016-02-29 09:57:54' 
AND REG_LOGGED_TIME<'2016-03-02 11:43:59.959' AND REG_TENANT_ID=-1234
```

There is *no* load on the server. What is causing this? What can we do to avoid this?

[screen shot sysdig api gateway process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBvwa.png)

Answer (score 0):

This particular query is the result of the registry indexing task that runs in the background. The REG_LOG table is being queried periodically to retrieve the latest registry actions. The indexing task cannot be stopped. However, one can configure the frequency of the indexing task through the following parameter that is in the registry.xml. See [1] for more information.

```
indexingFrequencyInSeconds
```

If this table is filled up, one can clean the data using a simple SQL query. *However*, when deleting the records, one must be careful not to delete all the data. The latest records of each resource path should be left in the REG_LOG table since reindexing of data requires at least one reference of each resource path.

Also, if required, before clearing up the REG_LOG table, you can take a dump of the data in case you do not want to loose old records. Hope this answer provides information you require.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Configuration+for+Indexing

Comment: That explains why the query happens every minute. Can you also explain why it fires 2 SQL requests per second for roughly a whole minute?